# Broken Camera - Galaxy S3

Tags: camera

The acrylic cover to the camera cracked open while in my pocket, now the camera is degrading. Is it possible to replace the camera on a Galaxy S3?

Comment: oh, just found this! http://dx.com/p/diy-repair-part-camera-lens-module-for-samsung-galaxy-s3-i9300-146464

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about the camera, but the lens and acrylic cover should be easy to change. Here is a [replacement](http://www.ebay.com/itm/New-camera-lens-frame-chassis-4-for-Samsung-Galaxy-S3-i9300-White-/280927022049) I found on ebay. It's quite cheap also.

P.S. I've just seen your comment :). Take this as an extension to your findings.